# Android Suite of UI controls?

Tags: android, user-interface, frameworks

When I write web apps I rely on frameworks like jQuery, likewise in WinForm I use DevExpress's UI.

Is there a UI framework with fancy looking buttons, graphics, transitions etc etc that I can rely on to build great looking apps ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Droid Fu
- AndroidX